# Text color cut with clip-path, but keep clickable content

Tags: css, clip-path

I'm trying to have some links change color based on the background. The issue is that for the clip-path to work it has to be set as position: absolute; over the content, so the content becomes unclickable, but I can't set pointer-events: none; otherwise the navigation items won't be clickable anymore.

I'd like to have this exact visual effect but the content, the navigation and the back link should all be clickable in all major browsers.

```css
.clipper-wrapper {
 position: relative;
}

.clipper-wrapper .clipper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
}

.clipper-wrapper--dark nav {
 color: black;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.clipper-wrapper--dark .back {
 color: black;
}

.clipper-wrapper--clear nav {
 color: white;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.clipper-wrapper--clear .back {
 color: white;
}

.clipper-wrapper .back {
 position: fixed;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 top: 50%;
}

.clipper-wrapper nav {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.clipper-wrapper nav a {
 color: inherit;
}

.content a {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #666;
 color: white;
}

.content a:hover {
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--clear">
  <div class="clipper ">
    <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--dark">
  <div class="clipper">
     <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--clear">
  <div class="clipper ">
    <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--dark">
  <div class="clipper">
     <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--clear">
  <div class="clipper ">
    <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--dark">
  <div class="clipper">
     <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--clear">
  <div class="clipper ">
    <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--dark">
  <div class="clipper">
     <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--clear">
  <div class="clipper ">
    <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clipper-wrapper clipper-wrapper--dark">
  <div class="clipper">
     <nav class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A Navigation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another Nav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#">A content Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just set "pointer-events: none;" to the class ".clipper-wrapper .clipper" and everythings works well

Comment: I can't, otherwise the navigation links won't be clickable anymore

Comment: You are right so you can add "pointer-events: none;" to the class ".clipper-wrapper .clipper" and then add "pointer-events: auto;" to the ".clipper-wrapper nav" and its solve your problem

Comment: That doesn't work in IE, ads the nav is inside the clipper element